# "She is one of the few people nowadays who actually seems to feel a sense of social responsibility."

Tags: grammar

I need to correct this sentence but I don't know how!

> She is one of the few people nowadays who actually seems to feel a sense of social responsibility.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: It's worth noting that this particular error is something that even most native speakers get wrong all the time, and most people won't even notice (I had to re-read the sentence myself to catch it), but it is still technically wrong, so it's good to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: what is the subject of the sentence.

If it is **she**, then it is she who **seems** (singular)

If it is **the few people**, then it is they who **seem** (plural)

If you look at it closely, she is one of **the people who seem**.

So changing **seems** to **seem** corrects the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> *She is one of the few people nowadays* [*who actually seem(s) to feel a*
>   *sense of social responsibility*].

The error lies with the verb: it should be "seem" not "seems".

The bracketed relative clause modifies "people": there is a set of people who actually seem to feel a sense of social responsibility and she is a member of this set. "People" is plural so a plural verb-form is required.

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about few people and she is one amongst them. People is plural...So the sentence should be...She is one the few people who actually seem to feel a sense of social responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

> She is one of the few people nowadays who actually seems to feel a
> sense of social responsibility.

What a tricky question!  We follow the noun (noun phrase) **after** *of*.

The verb we are considering is inside a relative clause, but that does not matter.

The answer is **seem**.

Note:

Few people seem to be in the mall today.

Few people read novels these days.

[Reference](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp):

> Rule 8. With words that indicate portions—e.g., a lot, a majority,
> some, all—Rule 1 given earlier in this section is reversed, and we are
> guided by the noun after of. If the noun after of is singular, use a
> singular verb. If it is plural, use a plural verb.
>
> Examples:

```
A lot of the pie has disappeared. 
A lot of the pies have disappeared. 
A third of the city is unemployed. 
A third of the people are unemployed. 
All of the pie is gone. 
All of the pies are gone. 
Some of the pie is missing. 
Some of the pies are missing.
```